# adb controls G1 keyboard LEDs, terminal emulator doesn't?

Tags: android, adb

At the moment the LEDs that light up the keyboard of the G1 (HTC Dream) are very quick to turn off, I time it at six seconds. This is a pain when using the phone in the dark as you must press a button in order to turn the lights back on if you look away even for a very short time.

Since my G1 is rooted I have access to the system files and when using adb to open a shell (`adb shell`) to the USB connected phone I can set the brightness file to a positive value using

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/keyboard-backlight/brightness
```

This keeps the keyboard on, until the screen is set to turn off (two minutes on my phone).

When I attempt the same using a Terminal Emulator or writing a simple app which should execute the same it does nothing despite both having root access. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though your phone is rooted applications will still run by default under their own non-root user IDs.

You'll need to request root access for your app.  In the Terminal this is done by entering the `su` command and [an answer to this question shows you how to do it in your app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653504/android-using-super-user-permissions-allowing-access).

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure I tried something similar but this way works and my keyboard is now quite visible. I can now continue working on linking the backlights to the visibility of the screen.