# Android edit .conf file programmatically

Tags: android, configuration, edit, root

I wish to add lines to a .conf file in the root folder programmatically from my app. My users will have root access, and my app's purpose is to help them edit a .conf file. Suggestions/tutorials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing root files cannot be done without root permission: [How to create/write file in the root of the android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079766/how-to-create-write-file-in-the-root-of-the-android-device)

Your users would have to have rooted devices and give the application root permission.

Comment: yeah I saw that, and mentioned that my users would have rooted devices. I want to know how to give my app superuser permissions? Sorry if this is unclear

Comment: Ah sorry- missed the bit about root access. Might try this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653504/android-using-super-user-permissions-allowing-access