# SuperUser command outputs in Android

Tags: android, su, root

I am trying to use SuperUser commands to create a list of files that are in a certain location.  I am using the method laid out in this post:

[Android using Super User Permissions ? allowing access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653504/android-using-super-user-permissions-allowing-access)

My specific code looks like this:

```
try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream()); 
            DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(process.getInputStream());

            outputStream.writeBytes("cd " + baseDirectory + "/system/app" + "\n");
            outputStream.flush();

            outputStream.writeBytes("ls" + "\n");
            outputStream.flush();

            outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n"); 
            outputStream.flush(); 
            process.waitFor();
        }  catch (IOException e) {

        }  catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
```

and it runs without any errors.  My problem is that I can't figure out how to produce any output.

Please note that in the code I am trying to get a list of Apps (I know I can do this in different ways) but I need it to work in a general case...

Answer (score 0):

After you flush the exit command try reading your DataInputStream:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
int read;
char[] buffer = new char[4096];
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    output.append(buffer, 0, read);
}
String result = output.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use su to get a list of installed packages

[How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run)

However in your code, you say it doesn't output anything. But what exactly would you like it to output (and where)? You never told it to display anything.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question.  I am trying to get a list of files, not necessarily installed packages and since I am accessing protected files, I do need to use SU.  Second, I know I didn't output anything, that's what I was asking help to do.  I can't figure out how to produce the output (say in a list) from the code above.